# Is it possible to draw line from view to another view

Tags: swiftui

#### Goal Example

- The user clicks 1st circle button and 2nd circle button
- Then the line will draw from 1st to 2nd
- **NOTE:** Button is movable

[image]

#### What've tried

- There are two `Heart` in `BoardView`. Each heart has `MovableCard`
- When `Heart` is tapped, then notify and pass self

```swift
struct Heart: View {
  var body: some View {
    MovableCard("heart.fill")
      .onTapGesture {
        // Notify this card is tapped
        NotificationCenter.default.post(heartOnTap, ["self":self])
      }
  }
}
```

- There is viewModel in BoardView that observes `heartOnTap`

```swift
struct BoardView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
  var body: some View {
    ZStack{
      Heart()
      Heart()
      Path{ path in
        path.move(to: viewModel.firstCard.POS ?? CGPoint(x: -1, y: -1))
        path.addLine(to: viewModel.secondCard.POS ?? CGPoint(x: -1, y: -1))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- `ViewModel` will listen `heartOnTap` for receiving `Heart: View`
- I send `Heart: View` not the tap position because it's movable.
- But `Heart` that conformed `View` doesn't have any access for directly getting its position

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var firstCard: Heart?
  @Published var secondCard: Heart?

  init() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
      selector: #selector(self.didTap(_:)), 
      name: heartOnTap, 
      object: nil)
  }

  @objc func didTap(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let heart = notification.userInfo?["self"] as? Heart else { return }
    if firstCard == nil {
      firstCard = HEARTPOSITION // <- Heart position for drawing the line
    }
    if secondCard == nil {
      secondCard = HEARTPOSITION // <- Heart position for drawing the line
    }
  }
}
```

#### Discussion

Is there a possible solution for drawing line from view to another view. (view is movable)

#### Alternative Goal

[DigicalSim (iOS)](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1130192861?mt=8&at=11lKmw)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing about your initial plan that is potentially problematic is that you're trying to store references to `View`s. In general, this shouldn't be done in SwiftUI as `View`s are meant to be transient. Instead, I'd suggest creating an identifiable model that you can use to keep track of each `View`.

The `View`'s position can be sent back up the `View` hierarchy using a `PreferenceKey`. Then, a `Path` can be drawn from the recorded positions in the parent view.

There are lots of little details here (like using `ForEach` for the heart views, the initial positions, etc) that are all changeable for your own circumstances. The important part is transmitting the positions up the hierarchy and then drawing a path based on those positions.

```
struct HeartModel : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
}

struct HeartView : View {
    var model : HeartModel
    @State private var offset = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    @State private var initialDragPosition = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .position(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
                .preference(key: ViewPositionKey.self, value: [model.id:offset])
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            self.offset = CGSize(width: initialDragPosition.width + gesture.translation.width, height: initialDragPosition.height + gesture.translation.height)
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            initialDragPosition = self.offset
                        }
                )
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var heartModels : [HeartModel] = [.init(), .init()]
    @State private var positions : [UUID:CGSize] = [:]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(heartModels) { heart in
                HeartView(model: heart)
            }
            
            Path { path in
                if let first = positions.first {
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: first.value.width, y: first.value.height))
                }
                positions.forEach { item in
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: item.value.width, y: item.value.height))
                }
            }.stroke()
            
        }.onPreferenceChange(ViewPositionKey.self) { newPositions in
            positions = newPositions
        }
    }
}

struct ViewPositionKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: [UUID:CGSize] { [:] }
    static func reduce(value: inout [UUID:CGSize], nextValue: () -> [UUID:CGSize]) {
        let next = nextValue()
        if let item = next.first {
            value[item.key] = item.value
        }
    }
}
```

[image]